# How to add LoF and LoT to ToC if tocloft package is loaded

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocloft

the moment I load the `tocloft` package and compile, my LoF and LoT are not listed in the ToC anymore. I have to have the Lists displayed in the ToC. I need the `tocloft` package for other reasons, so working without it is no option as well. 
Thanks in advance for your help!

without `tocloft` (this is how I want it to look like):

[image: without tocloft package]

with `tocloft`:

[image: with tocloft package]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}  

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tocloft` isn't really compatible to a `KOMA class`, e.g. `scrreprt`. Switch to `report` class, for example  and everything should be alright.

Comment: Maybe you can use KOMA to modify your LoF and LoT. What are your requests? (BTW:  For me KOMA is my favorite documentclass)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! @Marco Daniel My request is that in LoF and LoT it displays "Figure 1 ..." or "Table 1 ..." instead of just the default behavior "1 ..." (I was looking for other solutions than tocloft already but could not find one)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Really? I don't use it for years now -- I just don't like it, it's a personal distaste...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: After I have written my first letter with scrlttr2, I completely switched to KOMA. And Markus is one of the most active developers. It's a kind of honor and a silent thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

If there should be a prefix for the entries in LOF and LOT there is no need to load `tocloft`. You can simple use KOMA-Script option `listof=entryprefix`:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  listof=ignorechapter,% list entries not grouped by chapters
  listof=entryprefix% use prefix for list entries
]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Test}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Then `\figurename` (english default "Figure") and `\tablename` (english default "Table) will be used as prefixes.

To get another prefix for e.g. figures in LOF use `\newcaptionname` to define `\listoflofentryname`. Example:

```
\newcaptionname{english}{\listoflofentryname}{Fig.}
```

---

**Original answer**

Remove package `tocloft` and use the possibilities of package `tocbasic` to modify TOC, LOF and LOT. This package is loaded by all KOMA-Script classes automatically.

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc,listof=ignorechapter]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

If you really want to use package `tocloft` then add option `titles`:

```
\documentclass[listof=totoc]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast answer, the second option achieved exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Paul I have updated my answer to show how you can get a prefix for the entries in LOF and LOT using a KOMA-Script option. So there should be no need to load `tocloft`.